# Code Documentation First?

Tags: documentation

Has anyone ever tried creating a complete code documentation first, before actually writing the code? I was thinking about this earlier because I thought it would help to write a concrete interface and would make sure your initial design wasn't floored by making you think about how classes interact. Is this a good idea? Has anyone tried it? Ell

Comment: Yes.  It's a good idea.  People do it all the time.  What more do you want to know?

Comment: But it doesn't matter how **concrete** your design is if in implementing it you see a flaw... this is why BDUF and Waterfall methodologies tend to fail on large projects.

Comment: This is a subjective question. Someone has done it at least some of the time, so the answer is bound to be yes. I personally prefer to just jump in and make a prototype first, as I will inevitable rediscover a better design about 5 times in the process. When tackling something complex, I scratch something on a piece of paper first. If it is trivial, then I tend to just jump right in. StyleCop helps me to fill the gaps later.

Comment: It's a great idea, otherwise you end up with undocumented features.

Comment: @S.Lott  the simple fact that he's asking the question kind of implies he is looking for some more information as I'm pretty sure you were aware.  But it seems like you prefer making snide comments about other peoples faults.

Comment: okay so I guess this is going to be my 3rd question closed now? (thats 3 out of 3...) I'm sorry, I didn't know people do it all the time. That was in the question

Comment: @ell  It doesn't seem to me to be the kind of question that will be closed.  Though sometimes its hard to know.  I think its a valid question though I don't have the ability yet to vote on whether or not to keep it open.

Comment: It would be even better if you wrote acceptance tests, and then used TDD to fulfil those Acceptance tests ;).

Comment: @Kenneth: "kind of implies he is looking for some more information" Absolutely True.  "**What** more information?" is the problem.  There's a trick to using the site.  The trick is to ask specific and open-ended questions.  Any question that can be answered "yes" is a poor question.  It's impossible to guess what additional information is requested from a closed-ended yes/no question.

Comment: @S.Lott how about "Is this a good idea?" which was part of his question.  But perhaps you want him to explicitly put "Why?" on there too? Seems natural to me to explain why I'm saying yes/no as this is just a natural technique for good communication skills but I guess there are people too who need things spelled out.

Also he's brand new to the website which takes time to get used to.  Cut him a break.  He'll get there.

Comment: @Kenneth: I'm *offering* education.  I neither downvoted nor asked to close the question.  I suggested some clarification by answering the trivially asked question and providing the logical follow-up to get more information.  There isn't much more I can do to help someone ask a better question, is there?  What would you suggest as ways to help people ask better questions?

Comment: Thank you both of you for your help, I realize now that this question was a little open ended, but I guess I didn't know what to search for. Thank you and I will try to improve the quality of my questions in future.

Comment: @S.Lott well I'm attempting to offer education then too.  Sometimes certain things just need time and exposure then they self correct.  Other times a less abrasive approach is fine.  The WAY you say things and the little nit-picky things you focus on are the real issues in my mind.

Comment: Don't use TDD. Writing documentation first has all the same advantages, and none of the disadvantages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

It gets you thinking about what, exactly, your code is supposed to *do.*  The idea is that you could start with any part of the code and know exactly what needs to be done to complete that module.

It's also easier fix something on the drawing board than in the IDE.

Comment: Easier to fix, yes.  Easier to notice, rarely.  Designs almost always look good until you attempt to implement them.

Comment: @Chad That's true.  I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I disagree. Creating complete documentation first is far worse than just enough documentation to know where to go next.  Change happens.  There's no way to know if you are going in the right direction, and by the time you figure it out, you are way behind.  Go with what works, improve and fix it as you go, let the code be the most up to date documentation.

Comment: Of course as soon as you change your code to fix a bug or to meet a new requirement, your documentation is out of date. [Documentation as executable tests](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/59152/code-documentation-first/59156#59156) is the way to go!

Comment: Draw up (sketch/outline) ideas beforehand yes, but don't create documentation. Unless you prefer to waste a lot of effort because you'll be throwing away a lot of the initial effort as the design is put to practical application. Plus, only public or internal classes/methods should be fully documented (including full description as well as parameters). Private local stuff should have one-liners that describe what they do for future reference but anything more is a waste because they'll inevitably be skipped over during the documentation generation phase anyway.

Comment: http://24ways.org/2010/documentation-driven-design-for-apis/

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways of thinking about it:

1) Documentation as in Word documents, Wiki, etc. By definition you cannot have a complete code documentation because you don't have a code to document. You can try to document hight level design, assumptions, interfaces and contracts first.

2) Documentation as executable tests. There is a school of thought that states that executable unit tests is the best documentation. This school of thought also advocates this kind of documentation before writing the code (TDD). At the same time you don't write all the tests for the whole system right form the start. You break it down by use cases first, then you do tests and code per use case.

Comment: +1 for TDD.  Absolutely a better option than documenting, then having to change significant amounts of documentation if the code changes.

Comment: Also +1 for documentation in the form of TDD.

Comment: you CAN have complete product documentation before the product exists. I've done it, I've worked in projects where it was a requirement. You won't have screenshots, but you can have everything else (including Visio diagrams representing the location of elements on screen).

Comment: @jwenting I have too and it was a collection of diagrams as well as 200+ pages of word documents. Not only was it a complete waste of time but it required 2 months to produce and a significant amount of our PMs time to constantly update as the design evolved into the final product. It actually probably would've gone a lot faster with graphical mockups using Balsalmiq. Next time I work on a project where this is a requirement I'm going to make a point that another person should be assigned to manage it full-time because that's how much effort it takes to maintain.

Comment: +1 TDD for basic proofs of individual components and diagrams for overall design assumptions (emphasis on assumption because the actual design should be written as the best practical application not as a 1-1 implementation of the diagram, they're called assumptions for a reason). Full software documentation of all public/internal classes/methods/properties comes last through a documentation generator (all properties/returns/remarks should be filled in first) and all private/local stuff gets one-liners to describe what they do for future reference (private/local is ignored by the generator).

Comment: (cont) The last medium/large size project I did took one simple systems diagram that showed how all the systems interlinked (it was a multi-process multi-program application with a client/server that talked to a client/server on a remote host and used a DB as an intermediate data access layer). The only thing I didn't mock up before hand that I should've was the database schema layout. Creating class diagrams by hand is also dumb because many IDEs will generate them for you directly from the code (Visual Studio Pro actually has a really great tool for this build in).

Comment: Evan, if your design changes to the point where the product documentation no longer reflects what the product does by the time it gets to release, there's something else wrong in your project, and it's not the documentation cycle :) When I did it, the user manual effectively WAS the functional design document. It was signed off on by the customer, and the application built to function as stated in the manual. If they wanted changes, those would be incorporated in the next iteration, in its documentation, several months down the line.

Comment: Tests are not documentation, nor would anyone expect to see tests when reading documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with the documentation is classic waterfall model, and has all the pitfalls associated with that model. Broadly, the more you document the more you have to update when the requirements change. One benefit of starting with user documentation is that you might get feedback (and hence changes) sooner. But experience shows that most people are bad at mentally mapping documentation to actions. So we use prototypes instead, which allow people to actually use the software and give feedback that way.

One variation on "documentation first" is [literate programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming). Start by writing a description of what the program will do from a programmers perspective. Keep tweaking that until it compiles. Voila, a literate program.

Comment: Exactly!  Change happens.  Documentation rots.  Code is the truest form of documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I personally find it better to use diagrams (such as UML) to do simple modeling to show the flow of things.  This is much quicker than documenting things out in words and if done right can be just as descriptive.  I would be hesitant to do Full Documentation though because personally I haven't ever had a project I've worked on that hasn't changed through the course of programming it.

EDIT:  Some documentation though should be done as you go a long.  This makes it easier to do the full documentation later.

Answer (score 3):

Joshua Bloch discusses this very point in his interview for the book "Coders at Work".

Contrary to more orthodox and academic views, he advises something to the tune of your thoughts (maybe you have read it there yourself?): that before writing the documentation you have to understand what do you want from the system and get a more "real" feeling. For this purpose he would design part of the interfaces and some client code that uses them.

> The most important thing is to know what you’re trying to build: what
>   problem you’re trying to solve. The importance of requirements analysis
>   can’t be overstated. There are people who think, “Oh, yeah, requirements
>   analysis; you go to your customer, you say, ‘What do you need?’ He tells
>   you, and you’re done.”
>
> Nothing could be further from the truth. Not only is it a negotiation but it’s
>   a process of understanding. Many customers won’t tell you a problem;
>   they’ll tell you a solution. A customer might say, for instance, “I need you to
>   add support for the following 17 attributes to this system. Then you have to
>   ask, ‘Why? What are you going to do with the system? How do you expect
>   it to evolve?’” And so on. You go back and forth until you figure out what all
>   the customer really needs the software to do. These are the use cases.
>
> Coming up with a good set of use cases is the most important thing you can
>   do at this stage. Once you have that, you have a benchmark against which
>   you can measure any possible solution. It’s OK if you spend a lot of time
>   getting it reasonably close to right, because if you get it wrong, you’re
>   already dead. The rest of the process will be an exercise in futility.
>
> The worst thing that you can do—and I’ve seen this happen—is you get a
>   bunch of smart guys into a room to work for six months and write a 247-
>   page system specification before they really understand what it is they’re
>   trying to build. Because after six months, they’ll have a very precisely
>   specified system that may well be useless. And often they say, “We’ve
>   invested so much in the spec that we have to build it.” So they build the
>   useless system and it never gets used. And that’s horrible. If you don’t have use cases, you build the thing and then you try to do something very simple
>   and you realize that, “Oh my gosh, doing something very simple like taking
>   an XML document and printing it requires pages upon pages of boilerplate
>   code.” And that’s a horrible thing.
>
> -- Joshua Bloch, from an interview in "[Coders at Work: Reflections on the Craft of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430219483)" by Peter Seibel

If you're already thinking along these lines, it'd be good if you can get a hold of the book and read the whole interview. As I said, he is always very enlightening.

Comment: This is good advice, but good documentation includes usage of the API.

Comment: For the record, while I appreciate the edit, I think that quote might not have been the one I was thinking about. It seems tangentially related and more high level or related to the requirements phase. I think he said that before writing documentation he would start coding, writing client code that would use the interface in order to have a rough idea of the right interface and that (this is the counter intuitive part in my opinion) that should come first, before writing any low level design doc at all. Of course it's my fault for not having found the quote when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some people even go further and state that a company should completely work backwards, so

1. Write the press release
2. Write a FAQ
3. Define the customer experience
4. Write the User Manual
5. Start programming

See
http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2006/11/working_backwards.html

Answer (score 1):

Writing the *complete* code documentation first is probably overkill and somewhat reminiscent of the waterfall methodology. However, I've found that a more pragmatic approach is writing the *README* first. Here's why:

The README does *not* document every detail of your project. Instead, it typically contains the following info:

1. **Description**: short "sales pitch". Tell the reader why they should keep reading.
2. **Quick examples**: short code snippets or screenshots to support the description.
3. **Quick start**: how to get going, install instructions, and more examples.
4. **Further documentation**: links to the full docs and more info.
5. **Project organization**: who are the authors, how to contribute, how to file bugs.
6. **Legal notices**: license, copyright, and any other legal details.

Writing the "sales pitch" up front forces me to be crystal clear about why this project should exist and why developers should use it. The mere act of writing full sentences to describe the project often changes it for the better: you understand it better, develop new ideas, and uncover potential problems. It's also a great prioritization tool: anything in the "sales pitch" is a must-have!

The "quick examples" and "quick start guide" force me to think through the key use cases from the user's perspective. I've found that doing this before writing any code - before being bogged down in implementation details and tight deadlines - leads to much cleaner APIs and designs. Remember: programs should be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute ([SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)).

In "further documentation", I create an outline of the pieces that will need detailed documentation, to be done later. "Project organization" lets me figure out who will work on the project and the coding practices. "Legal notices"... well, may as well get those out of the way too.

Once you have this basic README in place, you have a document that's useful for discussion, design reviews, dividing up the work, and project planning. As you work on the project, frequently check back with the README to make sure you're still on track. Also, incrementally updating the README and the "further documentation" as you go means *all* your documentation will be done when the code is done, which is a much more pleasant experience than having to rush through documenting everything last minute.

For more info, check out the following:

1. [Readme Driven Development](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2010/08/23/readme-driven-development.html)
2. [The most important code isn't code](http://zachholman.com/posts/documentation/)
3. [You are what you document](http://brikis98.blogspot.com/2014/05/you-are-what-you-document.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to think about how classes interact? Why is that a bad thing? I actually think about the interactions before I even know what the classes are. That way the classes identify themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You should have some idea of what you plan to do before you write the code. The issue always is how do you keep what you've coded in synch with what you've written? Some say don't try, others say forget the initial docs and keep up the comments. Of course the code is always the canonical source. The issue then becomes whether it is worth the effort to document what the code does for those who come later or use the code. Anyone can figure out what a function does. The writer's job is to help someone understand in 5 minutes what anyone can figure out in an hour. Add up the deltas and determine your path.